# How can I get grouped windows in pandas? I.e. like WINDOW OVER ... PARTITION BY ... from SQL

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, window-functions, partition-by

Pandas window functions i.e. `rolling` work great. However coming from SQL I know, that windows can also be `PARTITIONED BY` some group.

How can I get grouped windows in pandas?
A:

```
df.groupby(['group']).rolling('10s').mean()
```

fails with:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'MultiIndex'
```

And if `df.rolling('10s', on='group')` is used, it only works in case 'group' is int i.e. in SQL some concrete number of preceding/following rows. How can I preserve the window by time?

## edit minimal sample:

```
import random
groups = ['A', 'B']
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': range(60), 'group': [random.choice(groups) for i in range(60)]},index=pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range(start='20160101', end='20160229')))
df.head()
```

The following works, but does not consider the groups:

```
df[['value']].rolling('2d').mean().head()
```

The following does not work for time windows:

```
df[['group','value']].rolling(3, on='group').mean().head()
```

and

```
df.rolling('2D', on='group').mean().head()
```

fails with: `window must be an integer` when trying to use a time window.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the index so you can group by. I think the issue with the index column.

`df.groupby(['col2','col3'], as_index=False)`

Comment: but if I drop the index, then I no longer can aggregate by time. I.e. your solution throws: `window must be an integer` as the independent no longer contains time information.

Comment: then use  `s.groupby(level=['first','second'])` in level specify the index columns

Comment: This does not work, as initially it is not a multi index, but only a time based index. i.e. The second column/level `group` is not in the index.